# how to subtract the column values of two tables when there is no record in second query

Tags: mysql

in my school application i want to know due amount of a student
so that in my

**fee_class_mapping** table i have the fees assigned to the class of the student as follows

```
+----------------------+------------+----------+------------+
| fee_class_mapping_id | fee_cat_id | class_id | fee_amount |
+----------------------+------------+----------+------------+
|                    1 |          2 |        1 | 10000      |
|                    2 |          2 |        2 | 15000      |
|                    3 |          3 |        1 | 2000       |
+----------------------+------------+----------+------------+
```

in **student_present_class_details** table i would have student class info

```
+----------------------+----------+
| student_admission_id | class_id |
+----------------------+----------+
|                    1 | 1        |
|                    2 | 2        |
|                    3 | 1        |
|                    4 | 1        |
+----------------------+----------+
```

by mapping **student_present_class_details** `class_id` and **fee_class_mapping** `class_id` i would get how much fee is assigned to the student

and there is another table which holds **fee_category** details

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+
| fee_cat_id | fee_cat_name | parent_id |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
|          1 | School Fee   |         0 |
|          2 | School Fee   |         1 |
|          3 | books        |         1 |
|          4 | Dhobi        |         0 |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

i would get the fee_category wise amount of a particular students total amount with following query

```
select f.fee_cat_name, sum(fcm.fee_amount) from  fee_class_mapping fcm ,student_present_class_details pd ,fee_category f 

where pd.class_id=fcm.class_id and f.fee_cat_id=fcm.fee_cat_id and pd.student_admission_id=4 group by fcm.fee_cat_id;
```

**out put**

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| fee_cat_name | sum(fcm.fee_amount) |
+--------------+---------------------+
| School Fee   |               10000 |
| books        |                2000 |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

i have another table called **fee_transactions** where i would have transaction details of student fee category wise, table structure is

```
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| transaction_id      | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| student_id          | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fee_cat_id          | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| amount_paid         | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| paid_on             | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| trans_receipt_no    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_concession_given | enum('Yes','No') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| payment_mode        | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| refrence_number     | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tdm_id              | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

from the above table i would get sum of the amount paid fee category wise as follows

```
select sum(ft.amount_paid) from fee_transactions ft where ft.student_id=4 group by ft.fee_cat_id;
```

**out put**

```
+---------------------+
| sum(ft.amount_paid) |
+---------------------+
|                3000 | //school fee
+---------------------+
```

i want subtract total amount - amount paid

so i wrote following query to do so

```
select f.fee_cat_name, sum(fcm.fee_amount)-(select sum(ft.amount_paid) from fee_transactions ft where ft.student_id=4 and ft.fee_cat_id=fcm.fee_cat_id group by ft.fee_cat_id) from  fee_class_mapping fcm ,student_present_class_details pd ,fee_category f

where pd.class_id=fcm.class_id and f.fee_cat_id=fcm.fee_cat_id and pd.student_admission_id=4 group by fcm.fee_cat_id;
```

**out_put**

```
+--------------+------------+
| fee_cat_name | paidAmount |
+--------------+------------+
| School Fee   |       7000 |
| books        |       NULL |
+--------------+------------+
```

in fee_transaction table i do not have entry for book fee , it has entry for school fee

**total school fee=10000 - paid amount 3000 = 7000** which is correct

for books fee i don't have record in fee_transaction table
so its not returning value

what i want is

```
 +--------------+------------+
    | fee_cat_name | paidAmount |
    +--------------+------------+
    | School Fee   |       7000 |
    | books        |       NULL | //2000 instead of NULL
    +--------------+------------+
```

how would i achieve it.

please help me out. thank you!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to replace `NULL` with 0 in the result of the subquery.

```
SELECT f.fee_cat_name,
       sum(fcm.fee_amount) - coalesce((SELECT sum(ft.amount_paid)
                                              FROM fee_transactions ft
                                              WHERE ft.student_id = 4
                                                    AND ft.fee_cat_id = fcm.fee_cat_id
                                              GROUP BY ft.fee_cat_id), 0)
       FROM fee_class_mapping fcm
            INNER JOIN student_present_class_details pd
                       ON pd.class_id = fcm.class_id
            INNER JOIN fee_category f
                       ON f.fee_cat_id = fcm.fee_cat_id
       WHERE pd.student_admission_id = 4
       GROUP BY fcm.fee_cat_id;
```

I also rewrote it to use exlicit `JOIN` syntax, which is recommended as it's easier to read and understand.